# How to open PDF Blob using browser's PDF viewer rather than downloading?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have an `ArrayBuffer` of data for a PDF file and I would like to open it using the built-in PDF viewer for the browser.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const blob = new Blob([pdfBuffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = fileName;
a.style.position = 'fixed';
a.target = '_blank';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

This always results in the PDF file being downloaded to the downloads folder on the device rather than opening in a new tab with the PDF viewer in the browser. I have tested this in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox with the same results.

I have done this before when the PDF was actually downloaded from the server itself by just setting the `Content-Disposition` header in the response, but I am unsure how to do this with a client-side `Blob` like this.

Comment: Have you tried passing the string returned from createObjectURL to window.open()?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `window.open()` on the result of `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` to open the PDF in a new window instead of downloading it. For example:

```
var blob = new Blob([pdfBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(blobURL);
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Looks like I could just remove the `a.download = fileName;` part from my code as well.

Comment: For me it's not working with Chome latest version

Comment: What if I had to embed that blob onto the existing page instead of opening in new tab?

Comment: For me it's working with Chrome version 122.0.6261.112

Answer (score 3):

Managed to do it very nicely in combination with pdfMake library.

```
//Preview PDF
export const previewDocument = (content) => {
  const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(content);
  // Get PDF blob and open in new window
  pdfDocGenerator.getBlob((blob) => {
    let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(blobURL);
  });
}
```