# Using pdfMake.createPdf() is it possible to createPdf from an existing blob?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, pdfmake

I would need something like this:

```
var docDefinition = {
            content: [blob]
        }
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
```

is this possible to set up an existing blob[pdf] inside document definition (using typescript)?

Comment: Why do you want to call `createPdf` when you already *have* a pdf?

Comment: @Bergi mainly to have a consistent API without to much refactoring. because some pdfs are created in a declarative way using createpdf some are downloaded from backend.

Comment: You mean an API with methods such as `.open()`, `.download()`, `.getDataUrl()` and `.getBlob()`? Which of those methods do you need?

Comment: It is a bit complex use case. So we already have those pdfs that are created with createPdf, and they use for instance getDataUrl, but also .getBase64(). and some methods return already interface that is returned from createPdf method. now I need exactly the same for my blob. So would be nice if I could wrap blob into pdfmake interface, and then everything would be working without bigger refactoring.

Comment: Surely you can wrap a blob in an object with a similar interface, but probably it's easier to just treat all those files as blobs (and also get blobs from `createPdf`), you can still convert those blobs into data urls or even base64 strings later when you need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that no, you can't do that with pdfmake.

Pdfmake is used to create/make a pdf file (in a declarative way), what you seem to want to do is to read one. If you want to add a blob to your document-definition-object I believe you can't unfortunately..

I would suggest you to use something else to read a pdf file from binary data.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173732/18495180) may do what you want to achieve.