Is it possible to set <embed> PDF content from a fetch request?
I have a fetch request that returns a PDF stream:
// from the php code:
public function getPdfContent() {
return response($pdf, 200)
    ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
}

And the fetch:
fetch(`/get-pdf-content)
    .then(response =>
       
    )

Is it possible to set an <embed> content to show the PDF as if I had put the URL directly as src?
<embed src="/get-pdf-content">

Because I am creating different PDFs in the backend then I want to dynamically set the <embed> content based on which button was clicked

Use createObjectURL to create a URL out of your binary PDF data, and then assign that URL as src of the embed element.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173732/1427878

(And revoke the object URL again afterwards, otherwise this is likely to cause memory leaks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL_static)

Maybe you can send the entire <embed> tag along with the src from the backend. Then use the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute in any <div> and give the whole <embed> tag gotten as response as the attribute's value.
This would automatically set the <embed> tag with whatever src value you assign it at the backend.
example:
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<embed src='...'>" }} />

